# Two dir's of identical ownership, but `cat > f` produces differently owned files

Tags: file-permissions, ubuntu-18.04, keybase

Why do myfile.txt and myotherfile.txt have different ownership?

The first directory, myhandle on my Desktop, was created using `sudo chown`.  The second directory under /run/... was created as a networked file system by keybase.

From my ~/Desktop/myhandle:

```
$ ls -l ..
total 0
drwx------ 1 me root 126 Nov 23 23:10 myhandle

$ ls -la
total 0
drwx------ 1 me root 126 Nov 23 23:10 .
dr-x------ 1 me root  46 Nov 20 01:50 ..

$ cat > myfile.txt
test

$ ls -la
total 4
drwx------ 1 me root 146 Nov 23 23:11 .
dr-x------ 1 me root  46 Nov 20 01:50 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    5 Nov 23 23:11 myfile.txt
```

From /run/user/1000/keybase/kbfs/private/myhandle

```
$ ls -l ..
total 1
drwx------ 1 me root 504 Nov 23 23:12 myhandle

$ ls -la
total 0

$ cat > myotherfile.txt
test

$ ls -la
total 1
-rw------- 1 me root 5 Nov 23 23:12 myotherfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path component `kbfs` sounds like its contents could be on another filesystem (`kbfs` is the name of the filesystem keybase uses).

It is not unheard-of for special file systems to not adhere to common expectations about permissions.

See also an old bug in keybase where, in its filesystem, it was reporting completely different permissions than it was actually using: https://github.com/keybase/kbfs/issues/212

Comment: Quick search reveals `/run/user/1000/keybase/kbfs` is indeed a mountpoint for [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem and the relevant executable is `kbfsfuse`.

Comment: I think what's happening - maybe you can tell me if this is right - is that when writing to this filesystem, it is actually keybase that's doing the writing, and keybase itself is running as user myself, but group root.  (Is that the way it works, that a running daemon has a user/group under which it runs?)  As a result files take on that ownership.

Comment: Filesystems are free to report whatever permissions they want and free to use whatever logic to decide who is allowed to do what on the filesystem. Most standard file systems are sticking to established conventions here, so that the user can predict which operations will be successful - but, really, nothing stops a filesystem from telling a user "nobody can write to this file" and, in reality, allowing everybody to do so.